# Libtorrent. Answer some questions

Tags: python, libtorrent

To begin with, English is not my native language, so it's hard for me to read the libtorrent documentation and all this question has been translated.
I ask you to answer these questions, if you know any of them, answer only him.
I am using libtorrent 2.0.7 and Python 3.8
It is not necessary to answer questions in python, I will try to figure it out even if you answer in c++

1. At the moment when the torrent is not loaded yet. How do I get all the files to be uploaded?
   At the moment when the torrent is loaded. How do I get the path to the files that were uploaded?
   (I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768656/python-libtorrent-get-file-list-names), but its answer stopped working because of deprecated)
2. I'm trying to use

```
handle.get_torrent_info()
```

to answer point 1, but returns

```
DeprecationWarning: get_torrent_info() is deprecated
```

I tried to look in the source file, but it doesn't say what to use instead of this function. Do you know?

3. I would like to set a download speed limit for the entire session. To do this, I found

```
session.download_rate_limit()
```

in its parameters , but when using it, it returns

```
DeprecationWarning: download_rate_limit() is deprecated.
```

I also tried to look in the documentation, but I didn't find it. I also didn't figure out what parameters it accepts, I tried int, but it returned an error. As in point 2, it is not written what to use instead of the outdated function. Do you know?

4. I would like the session to download only 1 torrent at a time, and the rest queued in the order of enabling the download from the pause state. How to do this, I do not know at all. Help please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python libtorrent, get file list names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768656/python-libtorrent-get-file-list-names)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the 1st and 2nd question:

```
test = handle.status()
for i in range(test.torrent_file.files().num_files()):
    print(test.torrent_file.files().file_path(i))
```